# Invocar los metodos de una clase de forma dinámica, recorriendo un ciclo con los nombres de los metodos a invocar?

Tags: c#

Es posible hacer que se ejecuten los métodos por medio de un arreglo en un ciclo? una vez lo logre hacer en Unity pero era una método de unity que se llama SendMessage(string nombre del metodo, parametros) y ejecutaba todos los método con el nombre name

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] x = {"a","b"};
        foreach (var y in x)
        {
            llamar a los metodos 
        }   
    }
    public static void b()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Metodo 2");
    }
    public static void a()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Metodo 1");
    }
```

aqui les adjunto el de unity

```
public void recibirDaño(int daño,float pos)
{
    float impulso = Mathf.Sign(pos-transform.position.x);
    gameObject.SendMessage("saltar", 1);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.left*impulso*100f*Time.deltaTime,ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    if (vida > 0)
    {
        vida -= daño;
    }
    if (vida <= 25)
    {
        gameObject.SendMessage("pocaVida", vida);
    }
}
```

aquí en unity el SendMensaje busca el método que tenga de nombre poca vida y le manda el parámetro de vida, si no mal recuerdo la clase del método debe de estar en el mismo namespace o/y en el mismo gameobject

Comment: Lee sobre reflection e invoke, y despues agrega la respuesta ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var metodos = new string[]{"a","b"};

      
        var program = new Program();

        // GetType() permite la reflexión sobre el objeto
        var programType = program.GetType();

         foreach(var metodo in metodos){

            programType
            // método para invocar un miembro del objeto
            .InvokeMember(
                metodo, // nombre del método
                // flag para indicar que el miembro a ejecutar es un método
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                null,null,null);

         }
        
           
    }
    
    public static void a(){
        Console.WriteLine("a");
    }
    public static void b(){
        Console.WriteLine("b");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En el caso que expone, debido a que los nombres de metodo son unicos (no hay metodos sobrecargados con el mismo nombre dentro de la clase) y no reciben parametros es posible hacerlo a través de un sencillo uso de Reflection

1. Incluir el espacio de nombre de Reflection

   ```
     using System.Reflection;
   ```
2. Declarar una variable para el tipo (`System.Type`), en este caso se declara `t` la cual se instancia con el descriptor de tipo de la clase `Program` a través de `typeof(Program)
3. Se obtiene una instancia `mi` de `System.Reflection.MethodInfo` para el descriptor del método. Su valor se obtiene a través del método `GetMethod` de la instancia 't' , según el nombre
4. Se realiza la invocacion del metodo desctrito por 'mi' a traves del metodo `invoke`

   ```
   public static void Main()
   {
       string[] x = {"a","b"};
       Type t = typeof(Program); //Obtiene el tipo de la clase program
       foreach (var y in x)
       {  
           //llamar a los metodos 
           Console.WriteLine("Invocando " + y); 
           var mi = t.GetMethod(y); //Se obtiene una instancia de System.MethodInfo a través del nombre del metodo

           //Se realiza la invocacion propiamente dicha
           // El primer parametro va null, porque el metodo que se va a invocar es un metodo de clase (static)
           // El segundo parametro va null porque el metodo no tiene parametros
           mi.Invoke(null,null); 
       }   
   }
   ```